# Asp mvc5 dropdownlist ajax result

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to show values selected in the dropdown list in a certain Div, I have this code below:

```
<select id="SelectedItem">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#SelectedItem').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ajaxGetValue", "Test")',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:$('#SelectedItem:selected').val()},
        success: function(){
            $('#ajaxDisplay').html('...');
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

and in the controller side I have:

```
   public PartialViewResult ajaxGetValue(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.str = id.ToString();
        return PartialView("Student");
    }
```

I want to show my result here:

```
<div id="ajaxDisplay">
```

but it just gives no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector should only be the ID of the element: `SelectedItem` (not SelectedItem:selected), e.g.:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#ajaxDisplay').html($('#SelectedItem').val());
});
```

http://jsbin.com/kuheg/1/edit?html,js,output

To update every time the select box changes, you'd change my example to include a event listener:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#SelectedItem').change(function() {
    $('#ajaxDisplay').html($('#SelectedItem').val());
  });
  $('#ajaxDisplay').html($('#SelectedItem').val()); //sets the HTMl from the default value
});
```

However, the problem is the same, you are sending null to the server for the data property of your AJAX object. Another possible culprit is the div - does it have a closing div tag? Hard to tell with the code provided.

jsbin updated.

Comment: Value doesnt change :( even in the jsbin example

Comment: The problem is with `$('#SelectedItem:selected').val()` - you need to change this to `$('#SelectedItem').val()` - I'm not attempting to debug your server communications since you've not indicated that this is a problem, this answer assumes your AJAX call is successful and shows a client side only illustration of the solution (jsbin updated)

Answer (score 0):

you need to take in the result on the success - like this:

```
$('#SelectedItem').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ajaxGetValue", "Test")',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:$('#SelectedItem:selected').val()},
    success: function(result){
        $('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you verify the controller method is returning what you're expecting and when?